Bootstrap Tooltip placement issue
I am facing issue while using the bootstrap tooltip , which i given its placement to "top" , and i have implement this tooltip on a username ,But issue is when username is of appropriate characters length , it shows the tooltip on top but when characters length is more , its shows tooltip right to the element and also includes a gap , it looks like tooltip is implemented on the right element not on the username field.
I have tried to change placement position of tooltip as left ,right ,top ,bottom , but its not working

From the docs, Tooltip position attempts to automatically change when a parent container has overflow: auto or overflow: scroll, but still keeps the original placement’s positioning. To resolve, set the boundary option to anything other than default value, 'scrollParent', such as 'window':
$('#example').tooltip({ boundary: 'window' })

